# PyTorch mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (100x200 and 100x9922)

Tags: python, neural-network, nlp, lstm, pytorch

I am trying to make a BiLSTM language model and am having some issues.

Model

```
class BiLSTM(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers, dropout_rate, tie_weights):
    super().__init__()

    self.num_layers = num_layers
    self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
    self.embedding_dim = embedding_dim

    self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers=num_layers, 
                        dropout=dropout_rate, batch_first=True, bidirectional=True)
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout_rate)
    self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_dim*2, vocab_size)

    if tie_weights:
      # Embedding and hidden layer need to be same size for weight tying
      assert embedding_dim == hidden_dim, 'Cannot tie weights, check dimensions'
      self.linear.weight = self.embedding.weight

    self.init_weights()

    self.hidden = None
    self.cell = None

  def forward(self, x, hidden):
    hidden_0 = torch.zeros(2*num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim).to(device)
    cell_0 = torch.zeros(2*num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim).to(device)
    output  = self.embedding(x)
    output, (h, c) = self.lstm(output, (hidden_0, cell_0))
    output = self.dropout(output)
    output = self.linear(output)
    return output, (h, c)

  def init_weights(self):
    init_range_emb = 0.1
    init_range_other = 1/math.sqrt(self.hidden_dim)
    self.embedding.weight.data.uniform_(-init_range_emb, init_range_emb)
    self.linear.weight.data.uniform_(-init_range_other, init_range_other)
    self.linear.bias.data.zero_()


  def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        hidden = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim)
        cell = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim)
        return hidden, cell
  
  def detach_hidden(self, hidden):
        hidden, cell = hidden
        hidden = hidden.detach()
        cell = cell.detach()
        return hidden, cell
```

Model params

```
vocab_size = len(vocab)
embedding_dim = 100
hidden_dim = 100
num_layers = 5
dropout_rate = 0.4
tie_weights = True
model = BiLSTM(vocab_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers, dropout_rate, tie_weights)
model.to(device)
```

Training:

```
import copy
import time

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
lr = 20.0  # learning rate
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, 1.0, gamma=0.95)

def train(model: nn.Module) -> None:
    model.train()  # turn on train mode
    total_loss = 0.
    log_interval = 200
    start_time = time.time()
    
    hidden = model.init_hidden(batch_size)
    
    num_batches = len(train_data) // bptt
    for batch, i in enumerate(range(0, train_data.size(0) - 1, bptt)):
        hidden = model.detach_hidden(hidden)
        data, targets = get_batch(train_data, i)
        seq_len = data.size(0)
        output, hidden = model(data, hidden)
        loss = criterion(output.view(-1, vocab_size), targets)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 0.5)
        optimizer.step()

        total_loss += loss.item()
        
        if batch % log_interval == 0 and batch > 0:
            lr = scheduler.get_last_lr()[0]
            ms_per_batch = (time.time() - start_time) * 1000 / log_interval
            cur_loss = total_loss / log_interval
            ppl = math.exp(cur_loss)
            print(f'| epoch {epoch:3d} | {batch:5d}/{num_batches:5d} batches | '
                  f'lr {lr:02.2f} | ms/batch {ms_per_batch:5.2f} | '
                  f'loss {cur_loss:5.2f} | ppl {ppl:8.2f}')
            total_loss = 0
            start_time = time.time()
```

Eval:

```
def evaluate(model: nn.Module, eval_data: Tensor) -> float:
    model.eval()  # turn on evaluation mode
    total_loss = 0.
    with torch.no_grad():
        for i in range(0, eval_data.size(0) - 1, bptt):
            data, targets = get_batch(eval_data, i)
            seq_len = data.size(0)
            output = model(data)
            output_flat = output.view(-1, vocab_size)
            total_loss += seq_len * criterion(output_flat, targets).item()
    return total_loss / (len(eval_data) - 1)
```

Training block:

```
best_val_loss = float('inf')
epochs = 50
best_model = None

for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
    epoch_start_time = time.time()
    train(model)
    val_loss = evaluate(model, val_data)
    val_ppl = math.exp(val_loss)
    elapsed = time.time() - epoch_start_time
    print('-' * 89)
    print(f'| end of epoch {epoch:3d} | time: {elapsed:5.2f}s | '
          f'valid loss {val_loss:5.2f} | valid ppl {val_ppl:8.2f}')
    print('-' * 89)

    if val_loss < best_val_loss:
        best_val_loss = val_loss
        best_model = copy.deepcopy(model)

    scheduler.step()
```

My problem is I am getting the following error.

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-345-453c3f2a9cad> in <cell line: 5>()
      5 for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
      6     epoch_start_time = time.time()
----> 7     train(model)
      8     val_loss = evaluate(model, val_data)
      9     val_ppl = math.exp(val_loss)

4 frames
<ipython-input-343-16d7ac1074e2> in train(model)
     20         data, targets = get_batch(train_data, i)
     21         seq_len = data.size(0)
---> 22         output, hidden = model(data, hidden)
     23         loss = criterion(output.view(-1, vocab_size), targets)
     24 

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

<ipython-input-340-c83c2df4172c> in forward(self, x, hidden)
     29     output, (h, c) = self.lstm(output, (hidden_0, cell_0))
     30     output = self.dropout(output)
---> 31     output = self.linear(output)
     32     return output, (h, c)
     33 

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
    112 
    113     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 114         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    115 
    116     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (100x200 and 100x9922)
```

The model dimensions seem to be the problem but I don't know how to adjust to the model to solve the issue.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks.

EDIT
Get batch returns

```
(tensor([[9893,    0,  171,    1,    1,  180,    4,  795,   13,   26],
        [9894, 1192,   58,    0, 9325,  190,  140,    4,    2,    0],
        [9896,    2,  109, 5437,   20,   12, 1022,    5,    6,    4],
        [9897,    2,   52, 1446,    5,  474,    9,   38,  192,    5],
        [9898,    3, 2850,   30, 3489,  655,   10,  212, 3915,  300],
        [9902,    1, 2150,    1, 1791, 1534,  141,   12,    4, 2853],
        [9903, 2526,    9,  161,   40,   17,    7,    5,  339,    4],
        [9904,   42,   10,   14,  775, 1931,  151, 1786, 1281,  893],
        [9905,   32, 1574,    2, 2088,  569,  154,   19,  799, 3353],
        [9906,  222,   43,    9,  342,  499,  290,    1,    0, 9253]],
       device='cuda:0'), tensor([9894, 1192,   58,    0, 9325,  190,  140,    4,    2,    0, 9896,    2,
         109, 5437,   20,   12, 1022,    5,    6,    4, 9897,    2,   52, 1446,
           5,  474,    9,   38,  192,    5, 9898,    3, 2850,   30, 3489,  655,
          10,  212, 3915,  300, 9902,    1, 2150,    1, 1791, 1534,  141,   12,
           4, 2853, 9903, 2526,    9,  161,   40,   17,    7,    5,  339,    4,
        9904,   42,   10,   14,  775, 1931,  151, 1786, 1281,  893, 9905,   32,
        1574,    2, 2088,  569,  154,   19,  799, 3353, 9906,  222,   43,    9,
         342,  499,  290,    1,    0, 9253, 9908,    6,  388,   31,   28,    0,
         559,  835,    7,   30], device='cuda:0'))
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I'm wondering if it's not something simple:
from nn.LSTM docs, batch_first – If True, then the input and output tensors are provided as (batch, seq, feature) instead of (seq, batch, feature). Note that this does not apply to hidden or cell states. See the Inputs/Outputs sections below for details. Default: False.
If you set this to False, then your batch dims should be 200x100 and this should work (maybe?)

Comment: I changed it to False and the error persists.

Comment: Also for batch_first, for the nn.LSTM, input dimensions should be (N, L, H) = batch size, sequence length, and hidden dimension, and output dimensions should be (N, L, 2*H). What are the dimensions for your inputs? I.e. What does get_batch return?

Comment: So when you have tie_weights = True, you're setting the linear layer weights to be the embedding layer weights. But the dimensions are not the same.

Comment: self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_dim*2, vocab_size)

    if tie_weights:
      # Embedding and hidden layer need to be same size for weight tying
      assert embedding_dim == hidden_dim, 'Cannot tie weights, check dimensions'
      self.linear.weight = self.embedding.weight

Comment: Thank you removing the weight tying has solved that issue and the training runs, although the model isn't learning. I made a edit showing what get batch returns.

Comment: When you say the model isn't learning, there's no change whatsoever in the return from the loss function? I'm curious to know why you're detaching the cell and hidden tensors? Maybe try with a single layer, remove clip_gradients, and simplify as much as possible to see if that helps.

Comment: On the first epoch, the first batch has an erro of 9.25, the rest is 9.2. I'll try that and see if it helps.